# Conflict between polynom packages and slovak babel

Tags: babel, incompatibility, polynom

My problem is the conflict between polynomial long division provided by the `polynom` package and Slovak `babel`.

I want to get the polynomial long division, I use the package `polynom` and the following command:

```
\usepackage{polynom}

\polyset{style=C,div=:,vars=x}
\polylongdiv{x^3-2x^2+3x-1}{x-1}
```

Without using slovak babel, the output is correct:

[image]

But when I add `\usepackage[slovak]{babel}`, I get

[image]

As you can see the output with slovak babel active is wrong.

Any idea what might be causing this behaviour is much appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: The question which this is a duplicate of is about Czech `babel`, but the problem is exactly the same.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the hint! It does not work exactly the same as with czech babel though. I just found out that shorthandoff{-} is not enough. Slovak babel uses shorthand for ^ character as well, so when I used \shorthandoff*{^-} it worked well. Thanks again!

Comment: I overlooked the problem with `^` , sorry.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is similar for the Czech language, but requires a slightly different solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[main=slovak]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{polynom}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchcmd{\polylongdiv}
  {\begingroup}
  {\begingroup\catcode`^=7 \shorthandoff{-}}
  {}{}

\polyset{style=C,div=:,vars=x}

\begin{document}

\polylongdiv{x^3-2x^2+3x-1}{x-1}

\end{document}
```

[image]